# Select first row (grouping) + add aggregate function

Tags: postgresql, aggregate, postgis, window-functions

First have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3800551/568884) on StackOverflow.

I'm looking to accomplish the same task, except I also need to add an aggregate function (PostGIS's `ST_Union`) to my query.

How can I combine the [answer using `DISTINCT`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7630564/568884) with an aggregation...

I've tried:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (name, zonedistrict_id)
       ST_Union(geom) as geom, gid, name, zonedistrict_id, zonestyle_id, longname 
FROM zones
ORDER BY name, zonedistrict_id, zonestyle_id;
```

Which screams:

> `column "zones.gid" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`

Which is strange, because if I remove `ST_Union(geom) as geom,`, the query works. But it's absent of the union'd geometry.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Answer to question

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (name, zonedistrict_id)
       ST_Union(geom) as geom, gid, name, zonedistrict_id, zonestyle_id, longname 
FROM   zones
GROUP  BY gid, name, zonedistrict_id, zonestyle_id, longname
ORDER  BY name, zonedistrict_id, zonestyle_id;
```

It depends on what you are actually trying to achieve and what version of Postgres you are using and the table definition of the underlying table. You chose not to disclose any of that.

This gives you one distinct row per `(name, zonedistrict_id)`, but `geom` is only the aggregate over `(gid, name, zonedistrict_id, zonestyle_id, longname)`

In older versions you had to list every non-aggregated column of the `SELECT` list in the `GROUP BY` list. This changed somewhat with PostgreSQL 9.1. [I quote the release notes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/release-9-1.html):

> Allow non-`GROUP BY` columns in the query target list when the primary
> key is specified in the `GROUP BY` clause (Peter Eisentraut)

#### My guess

However, I suspect you secretly want this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (name, zonedistrict_id)
       ST_Union(geom) OVER (PARTITION BY name, zonedistrict_id) AS geom
     , gid, name, zonedistrict_id, zonestyle_id, longname 
FROM   zones
ORDER  BY name, zonedistrict_id, zonestyle_id;
```

Using a `ST_Union(geom)` as *aggregate window function*. So `geom` is actually the aggregate over `(name, zonedistrict_id)`, which seems more likely.

This should be possible since the [PostGis manual tells us about its aggregate functions](https://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.0/PostGIS_Special_Functions_Index.html#PostGIS_Aggregate_Functions):

> ... can be used just like any other sql aggregate function such as sum, average.

And SQL aggregate functions can be used as window functions.

Comment: You secretly guessed right. This is exactly what I needed. Thank you! Not only did this solve my problem, it also forced me to move my Postgres data onto a new AWS EBS because initially I was getting `ERROR:  could not write block n of temporary file: No space left on device`. I reserved 25 GB, moved Postgres onto it (with XFS) and query returned successfully. Thx!