# Unexpected behaviour for GROUP BY query

Tags: postgresql, group-by, aggregate, postgresql-9.4

```
CREATE TABLE public.temp (
   id integer, 
   a integer, 
   b integer, 
   x integer
);

select x, a, b
    from temp
group by id, a, b;
```

ends up with expected error:

> ```
> ERROR:  column "temp.x" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
> LINE 1: select x, a, b
>                ^
> ```

However, after adding primary key:

```
ALTER TABLE ONLY temp ADD  PRIMARY KEY (id);
```

... the previous `SELECT` query runs without error.

Why can column `x` now be used without aggregation?
Is the behaviour documented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `PRIMARY KEY` in the `GROUP BY` clause explicitly covers the whole row since Postgres 9.1. [The release notes:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/release-9-1.html)

> Allow non-`GROUP BY` columns in the query target list when the primary key is specified in the `GROUP BY` clause (Peter Eisentraut)

[The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-GROUPBY)

> When `GROUP BY` is present, or any aggregate functions are present, it
> is not valid for the `SELECT` list expressions to refer to ungrouped
> columns except within aggregate functions or when the ungrouped column
> is functionally dependent on the grouped columns, since there would
> otherwise be more than one possible value to return for an ungrouped
> column. A functional dependency exists if the grouped columns (or a
> subset thereof) are the primary key of the table containing the
> ungrouped column.

Related:

- [Select first row (grouping) + add aggregate function](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/41494/select-first-row-grouping-add-aggregate-function/41537#41537)

Comment: Unique non-NULL column covers the whole row too. Does it acts similarly?

Comment: @Akina: No, (currently) only the PK is taken into consideration. (The SQL standard knows of additional functional dependencies.)

Answer (score 2):

`GROUP BY` by primary key column causes each row to become a separate group. In this case the column not included into grouping / aggregating has only one value within the group, so this value may be returned without ambiguity.

If there is no primary column / expression as a part of grouping expression then server must consider that there may be more than one value for a group, and it generates error because of possible ambiguity.

In general the fact that the error is not generated is an extension it seems...

If PK is a part of grouping expression than formally all another parts are excess. I.e. if `id` is PK then `group by id`, `group by id,a,b,x`, `group by id,a,b`, `group by id,b,x`, `group by id,a,x`, ... will have the same meaning and effect.

But the best practice is to use an aggregate function for each non-groupby column / expression in any case.