# Build a select query that includes aggregated values from a different table

Tags: postgresql, query, pivot, aggregate-filter

I have two tables in Postgres: polls and votes.

The first one `polls` is designed to contain the poll-related data. Every poll is aimed to have only two possible responses — `option_a` and `option_b`

```
+----+---------+----------+----------+------------+
| id | author  | option_a | option_b | created_at |
+----+---------+----------+----------+------------+
| 1  | user_01 | apple    | banana   | 2020/08/15 |
+----+---------+----------+----------+------------+
| 2  | user_02 | tea      | coffee   | 2020/08/16 |
+----+---------+----------+----------+------------+
```

The second one `votes` is holding data about the votes:

```
+---------+---------+--------+------------+
| poll_id | voter   | option | voted_at   |
+---------+---------+--------+------------+
| 1       | user_01 | apple  | 2020/08/15 |
+---------+---------+--------+------------+
| 1       | user_02 | banana | 2020/08/15 |
+---------+---------+--------+------------+
| 1       | user_03 | banana | 2020/08/15 |
+---------+---------+--------+------------+
| 1       | user_04 | apple  | 2020/08/15 |
+---------+---------+--------+------------+
| 1       | user_05 | apple  | 2020/08/15 |
+---------+---------+--------+------------+
| 2       | user_01 | tea    | 2020/08/16 |
+---------+---------+--------+------------+
| 2       | user_08 | coffee | 2020/08/16 |
+---------+---------+--------+------------+
```

What I'm trying to do is to select polls with votes count.
E.g. for selecting the data for poll with `id = 1`, I expect to get:

```
+---------+----------+----------+------------+
| poll_id | option_a | option_b | created_at |
+---------+----------+----------+------------+
| 1       | 3        | 2        | 2020/08/15 |
+---------+----------+----------+------------+
```

How to compose such a query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use filtered aggregation for this:

```
select v.poll_id, 
       count(*) filter (where v.option = p.option_a) as option_a, 
       count(*) filter (where v.option = p.option_b) as option_b,
       max(p.created_at) as created_at
from votes v 
  join polls p on p.id = v.poll_id
group by v.poll_id
order by v.poll_id;
```

The `max(p.created_at)` is necessary to make the `group by` happy.

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=273db6b75e0b21d71b6ca41e1e9a138b)

Answer (score 1):

#### One query for *all* polls

Use the aggregate `FILTER` clause, like a_horse already suggested. See:

- [Return counts for multiple ranges in a single SELECT statement](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/93510/return-counts-for-multiple-ranges-in-a-single-select-statement/93522#93522)

```sql
SELECT p.id AS poll_id  -- ① PK column!
     , min(ct) FILTER (WHERE v.option = p.option_a) AS option_a 
     , min(ct) FILTER (WHERE v.option = p.option_b) AS option_b
     , p.created_at     -- ① no aggregate
FROM  polls p
LEFT  JOIN (  -- ②
   SELECT poll_id, option, count(*)::int AS ct
   FROM   votes
   GROUP  BY 1, 2
   ) v ON v.poll_id = p.id
GROUP  BY 1
ORDER  BY 1;
```

① Assuming that `polls.id` is the `PRIMARY KEY`, `polls.created_at` is covered this way and does not have to be aggregated. See:

- [Select first row (grouping) + add aggregate function](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/41494/select-first-row-grouping-add-aggregate-function/41537#41537)

② Aggregate first, join later. That's typically faster. See:

- [Slow queries related to subqueries using aggregation](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/54719/slow-queries-related-to-subqueries-using-aggregation/54722#54722)

And `LEFT JOIN` to keep polls with no votes in the result.

#### `crosstab()` query for *one* poll

`crosstab()` provided by the additional module tablefunc is typically faster. In this case, however, with only two options per poll and the need to access table `polls` twice, it's probably slower:

```sql
SELECT v.*, p.created_at
FROM   crosstab(
   'SELECT poll_id, option, count(*)::int
    FROM   votes
    WHERE  poll_id = 1
    GROUP  BY 1, 2
    ORDER  BY 1, 2'

  ,'SELECT o.*
    FROM   polls, LATERAL (VALUES (option_a), (option_b)) o
    WHERE  id = 1'
   ) AS v (poll_id int, option_a int, option_b int)
JOIN polls p ON p.id = v.poll_id;
```

See:

- [PostgreSQL Crosstab Query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11751905/939860)

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=9231778979d95d05911343ed09e03d7e)*

Comment: As always — shiny answer!